# Scrape date and link from a HTML table where both items are separated by different tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a long table with links and dates. See the HTML code below. The data in the table is well-structured: All the information appears in blocks, with a date (`isodate`) between `dt` tags and the link between `dd` tags.

Using Python and BeautifulSoup, I want to get the date and the link for each block.

```
<dt isodate="2022-02-10">
<div class="date">10 February 2021</div>
</dt>
<dd>
<div class="testa"><span class="testy"><a class="row" href="https://www.bla.html" lang="en"> <span class="full">English</span></a></span></div>
</dd>

<dt isodate="2022-02-12">
<div class="date">12 February 2021</div>
</dt>
<dd>
<div class="testa"><span class="testy"><a class="row" href="https://www.bli.html" lang="en"> <span class="full">English</span></a></span></div>
</dd>
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use beautiful soup `find_all` and `find_next_sibling` methods to select the `dt`s and the sibling `dd`s as below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
    <dt isodate="2022-02-10">
    <div class="date">10 February 2021</div>
    </dt>
    <dd>
    <div class="testa"><span class="testy"><a class="row" href="https://www.bla.html" lang="en"> <span class="full">English</span></a></span></div>
    </dd>

    <dt isodate="2022-02-12">
    <div class="date">12 February 2021</div>
    </dt>
    <dd>
    <div class="testa"><span class="testy"><a class="row" href="https://www.bli.html" lang="en"> <span class="full">English</span></a></span></div>
    </dd>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

items = []

for item in soup.find_all('dt'):
    date = item.get('isodate')
    url = item.find_next_sibling('dd').select_one('div a').get('href')
    # add a dict to the items list
    items.append(dict(date=date, url=url))

print(items)
```

**output**

```sh
[
{'date': '2022-02-10', 'url': 'https://www.bla.html'}, 
{'date': '2022-02-12', 'url': 'https://www.bli.html'}
]
```

Comment: One question: one thing though, I want only the links with `class="row"`- how can that be achieved?

Comment: Add the `.row` class selector in the select one method. `url = item.find_next_sibling('dd').select_one('div a.row').get('href')`

Answer (score 1):

Here index.html consisted of

```
<html>
<body>

    <dt isodate="2022-02-10"><div class="date">10 February 2021</div></dt>
    <dd>
        <div class="testa"><span class="testy"><a class="row" href="https://www.bla.html" lang="en"> <span
            class="full">English</span></a></span></div></dd>

    <dt isodate="2022-02-12"><div class="date">12 February 2021</div></dt>
    <dd>
        <div class="testa"><span class="testy"><a class="row" href="https://www.bli.html" lang="en"> <span
                        class="full">English</span></a></span></div></dd>
</body>
</html>
```

Python code used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html") as html_content:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
date = [x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all('div',class_='date')]
link = [x['href'] for x in soup.find_all('a',href=True)]
```

- For Date:

find_all will find the div class = 'div' and return list of all the tags that match.

```
[<div class="date">10 February 2021</div>, <div class="date">12 February 2021</div>]
```

From here you can extract the date via `x.get_text()`

- For Link:

find_all will find the a tag which contains href values (when href=True) and return a list of all tags that match.

```
[<a class="row" href="https://www.bla.html" lang="en"> <span class="full">English</span></a>, <a class="row" href="https://www.bli.html" lang="en"> <span class="full">English</span></a>]
```

From here you can extract the href data using `x['href']`

Output: A list of date and urls can be accessed separately.

`['10 February 2021', '12 February 2021'] ['https://www.bla.html', 'https://www.bli.html']`